# Fatal error: Class 'App\PDO' not found in

Tags: php, namespaces, pdo

I get this error when I try to use namespaces.

I have

`namespace App;`

the top, and the class looks like

```
class database{

  function __construct(..)
    try{
      $this->db = new PDO(...)   <-- here the error
    ...
  }
}
```

I dont' understand how do namespaces work? Shouldn't PHP fallback to the default PDO class if app/PDO is not found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't PHP fallback to the default PDO class if app/PDO is not found?

No, it should not.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/language.namespaces.fallback.php):

> Class names always resolve to the current namespace name. Thus to access internal or non-namespaced user classes, **One must refer to them with their fully qualified Name**

For your specific example, the fully qualified name for `PDO` would be `\PDO`.

Comment: Any idea why \PDO doesn't work for me? I use PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: I figured it out. Just had to add `use PDO;` after the namespace and before the class.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `use PDO;` after the namespace and before the class.

Comment: This fixed my problem.