# How to execute more than one statement in try command

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

I am trying to establish a `PDO` connection using the try block and then printing a success message after the connection gets established. My code is as follows:

> index.php :

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$con = new \app\db\Connect();


if ($con)
{
  echo 'connection successful.';
}
```

> connect.php

```
<?php
namespace app\db;

class Connect
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    // set the connection variables
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'pdoposts';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root';

    // create the DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' .$dbname;

    // create PDO connection
    try {
      static $con;
      $con = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $con;
  }
}
```

My problem is that there is no way for me to use the `$con`created in the `try - catch` command in the `index.php` file. I am very sorry if this question seems very basic and elemental one, but please help me understand how it can work. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have also visited this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252415/how-to-pass-pdo-variable-to-another-class  but nothing I understood!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoring to the answer below:
[The solution here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9177991/2922479)

I just added the backslash right before `PDO` and made it to be `\PDO` and it is now working properly. The link below can help understanding `PHP Callbacks` and how they work better:
[Using namespaces: fallback to global function/constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

I should have kept in mind the `namespace` from which I wanted to use `PDO` from. In this case, using a `\` would tell php to use PDO from the `Global Namespace` and not from the namespace from which the code runs in `(app\db)`.